# How to deal with bad edits

Tags: discussion

What is the best way to deal with incorrect edits?

For example https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5293922 the edit was adding an incorrect tag and nothing else. The edit was approved by 3 people.

I can see two potential actions:

- Create another edit that removes the tag.
- Flag the question for moderator attention and explain the situation.

Which (if any) of these is correct?

Comment: Just close the question, as it has all sorts of problems that aren't really recoverable.  Lipstick, pig, etc..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, make double-sure that the edit is actually incorrect. If you're *not sure* then move on - much time is wasted arguing over edits that *really don't matter*. Yes, there are a lot of edits that are just a waste of time, but if they *do no harm* then putting further work into correcting them just adds to the damage.

Once you're sure,

1. Fix it. Roll back, re-edit, whatever. **Always make sure you're significantly improving the post** - I really cannot stress this enough.
2. Leave a comment for the editor. Yes, you can ping editors by typing `@<editorname> your edit was harmful due to <reason>` or some such in a comment on the post that was edited. Not a lot of folks realize this, and the end result is that folks get all frustrated by edits instead of just educating the editors.

That's *usually* all you need to do. In particular **do not flag for moderator attention over a single edit that you could fix yourself** - you're just delaying the correction, which helps no one. If you see a *pattern* of incorrect or abusive edits, *then* flag one of the edited posts and include links to others in your message to the moderators.

Comment: Thanks, since making this post `1` has been handled by others, and I have done `2` although I'm not entirely sure it worked (`@<editorname>` was not linkified).

Comment: Pinging an editor does not provide autocomplete suggestions like pinging any other participant, which led me to believe the ping would not notify the recipient, until I found this answer.