# When approving an edit, how to send a message to the editor?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I recently came across an edit that, while mostly appropriate, had to be slightly modified. It would be great to be able to send a note to the original editor indicating why an edit might have been rejected or edited, or provide some general feedback. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can ping any editor of the post using @username in the comments. You'll have to write username by hand, it won't auto-complete. This will notify that user in their global inbox.

From [Shog9's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265638/2982225):

> Leave a comment for the editor. Yes, you can ping editors by typing
> *@ your edit was harmful due to*  or some such in a
> comment on the post that was edited. Not a lot of folks realize this,
> and the end result is that folks get all frustrated by edits instead
> of just educating the editors.

### Related post:

- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/245167)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing that, but it wasn't the sort of thing that I felt belonged in the comments of a post. Especially since that author's name didn't appear as editor any longer, it would have been a bit out of place.

Comment: @remus Inviting them to a chat room is also an option. You can create a room for them and yourself, or invite them to a more general room like the [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) where all users are present and the discussion is more friendly and casual, rather than focused on the user.